# No mapping found error in dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a beginner in Spring MVC and while trying to create a `Spring MVC` application I am getting the below **error**:

```
no mapping found for http request with uri [/SpringMVCHibernateCRUD] in dispatcherservlet 'appServlet'
```

Following are the files:

**Web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.jwt" />

<!-- Getting Database properties -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction -->
<bean id="transactionManager"

 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
 </beans>
```

EDIT:

Controller

```
 @Controller
 public class EmployeeController {

 private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

 public EmployeeController() {
    System.out.println("EmployeeController()");
 }

 @Autowired
 private EmployeeService employeeService;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/")
 public ModelAndView listEmployee(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
    List<Employee> listEmployee = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    model.addObject("listEmployee", listEmployee);
    model.setViewName("home");
    return model;
 }
```

Changing from `/` to `/*` did not solve the and I already have the `@controller` annotation on the controllers. Can someone please help me with the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the contoller?  Do you have a mapping for the URL like  @RequestMapping(value = "/SpringMVCHibernateCRUD" )?

Comment: Can we see the controller class?

Comment: Please include your controller class.

Comment: `servlet-context.xml` I think your issue is with dispatcher servlet config. Please paste entire code if you can. Check whether your controller class is out of the component scan. It is better to avoid XML based configuration and use java based configuration.

Comment: Is `xsd ` and spring versions are matching? If you getting any console error please add entire stack trace.

Comment: You've no mapping to `SpringMVCHibernateCRUD` as mentioned above by @karen

Comment: @achAmháin Did that still the same error.

Comment: @SumeshTG dont have any errors in the project..

Comment: `SpringMVCHibernateCRUD` You should map this URL in controller in order to access.

Comment: Does your controller also have a request mapping?  If so you would need to use that mapping plus the extra slash /

Comment: Could you post the project folder hierarchy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, apparently a simple clean and build resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

change your servlet mapping with this and try ;

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In your `web.xml` , your `url-pattern` is only `/`  . Change with `/*` to send request to any url.

Comment: Did it..Same issue

Comment: Also add @requestmapping on your controller class with related mapping

Comment: Added..still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```